# Kotlin set attributes on a dynamically added edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am trying to learn Kotlin, and I want to create a number of **EditText**'s dynamically placed next to each other on the screen of an android phone.

The amount of **EditText**'s is based on the length of a word that the user has to guess. So if the word is *dog* then the user should be presented with an **EditText** for each letter in the word.

So I did something like this.

```
for (letter in word) {
    val editText = EditText(this)
    ...
}
```

and then append them to a linear layout.
But I want to set some **attributes** on the edittext before i append it and for that I am totally lost.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Please help i am very fustrated... :-)

Comment: why not use RecyclerView for that? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what attributes you want to add to the edit text you could create an XML layout for it. You could set the textColor, background etc and then inflate the layout.

so in your for loop you'd do something like this

```
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val editText = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourCustomEditText, null, false) as EditText
// add to editText to your linearLayout as you're already doing
```

and then YouCustomEditText would be an xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_vew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:hint="hint"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"></EditText>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I dont understand what the inflaterTag is :)

Comment: Sorry typo - should just be inflater

Answer (score 1):

Create an xml layout with EditText

input_edittext_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/input_letter_edittext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:padding="8dp"
/>
```

add a LinearLayout in your main layout where ever you want to show with an id

activity_words.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".WordsActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/letter_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

WordsActivity.kt

```
class WordsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val wordlist = listOf("Cat", "dog", "Tiger", "Elephant")
lateinit var wordlayout: LinearLayout
val currentEditTextList = mutableListOf<EditText>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_words)
    wordlayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.letter_input_layout)
    findMatchedString("Elephant")//example calling from here 

}
//String passed as argument to compare from word list
fun findMatchedString(inputString: String){
    wordlist.forEach {
       if(it == inputString){
           addEditTextToLayout(inputString)
       }else{
           //Handle your logic to handle else case
       }
    }
}

fun addEditTextToLayout(matchedString: String) {

    //first adding EditText objects to list
    matchedString?.let {
        it.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
            val editText = getInputEditText()
            editText.tag = index
            editText.setText(element.toString())//This line added to check the 
        each letter on the each EditText separately
            currentEditTextList.add(editText)
        }
    }

    //second adding each EditText from list to layout
    currentEditTextList?.let {
        if (it.size > 0) {
            it.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
                element.tag = index
                wordlayout.addView(element)
            }
        }
    }
}


fun getInputEditText() : EditText{
return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_edittext_layout, null, false) as 
EditText
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am trying it now